# Automatic if statement with sequence condition in sql

Tags: c#, sql, database, uwp

I have a "undangundang.db" database. I want if the filename contains the word 2019, then folder_id = 2, if 2018 then folder_id = 3, and so on (sequentially from 2019 to 1945 with folders_id 2 to 76).

How do I check it, for example I have a filename: UU No 01 Th 2016 - Penjaminan , then folder_id = 5?

Code:

```
SQLiteConnection objConnUpdate = new SQLiteConnection("uuthemis.db");
    var increment = 1;

                    var currentFile = 2019;
                        var currentFolder = 2;
                        var minFile = 1945;

                        while (minFile <= currentFile)
                        {
                            currentFile -= increment;
                            currentFolder += increment;
                        }
                        if(currentFile <= minFile)
                        {
                            string update = @"INSERT INTO undangundang (uu_id, folder_id, identifier, filename, folder_parent_id) SELECT null, " + currentFolder + ",'" + itemDetail.Judul.Split('-')[0].TrimEnd() + "'," +
                    "'" + itemDetail.File + "',2 WHERE not exists (select uu_id and folder_id and identifier and filename and folder_parent_id FROM undangundang where uu_id=null and folder_id=" + currentFolder +
                    " and identifier='" + itemDetail.Judul.Split('-')[0].TrimEnd() + "' and filename ='" + itemDetail.File + "' and folder_parent_id=2)";
                    var updateQuery = objConnUpdate.Prepare(update);
                            var updateQuery = objConnUpdate.Prepare(update);
                            updateQuery.Step();
                        }
```

I have a problem, which is always entering folder_id = 77. How to handle it?

Comment: This is because `var increment = 1; var currentFile = 2019; var currentFolder = 2; var minFile = 1945; while (minFile <= currentFile) { currentFile -= increment; currentFolder += increment; }` is equal to `var currentFile = 1944; var currentFolder = 77; `

Comment: how to check if 2016 is currentfolder=5?

Comment: Your question is unclear in general. First, what do you mean by _"if the file contains the word 2019"_? Do you mean _"if the **filename** contains word 2019"_ (like "uuthemis_2019.db", or "u2019uthemis.db")? Or maybe you mean _"if the **file path** contains word 2019"_ (like "C:\Temp\2019\uuthemis.db")?

Comment: i mean is filename. For Example: UU No 01 Th 2016 - Penjaminan

Comment: why  2019 = 2, 2015 = 3, do u mean folder id increments by 1 every 4 years?

Comment: No, automatic increment every 1 year. So there are files with 1945-2019 with folders_id 2 to 76

Comment: @Rose Ok, you've better edit your question to show this. Next, do you have some code, that will extract this year number from filename?

Comment: Also, as @AnsonFong mentioned, your question states that _"if **2015** will enter folder_id = 3"_, do you mean _"if **2018** will enter folder_id = 3"_?

Comment: i have edited the code above

Comment: @Rose, Ok, do you have some code, that will extract this year number from filename string? Something like `var yearFromFilename = GetYearFromFilename("UU No 01 Th 2016 - Penjaminan");`

Comment: itemDetail.Judul.Contains(currentFolder.ToString())

Comment: it will always return 77 because your while loop is not making any sense. Can you please add some comments in your code so that i can provide the solution of your code?

Comment: the loop is used to make automatic if sequentially. Or is there another way?

Comment: And what happens if your filename contains 2 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that your loop:

```
var increment = 1;
var currentFile = 2019;
var currentFolder = 2;
var minFile = 1945;

while (minFile <= currentFile)
{
    currentFile -= increment;
    currentFolder += increment;
}
```

is just iterating `currentFile` from 2019 to 1944 and doesn't check anything (however, in comments you noted that you check `itemDetail.Judul.Contains(currentFolder.ToString())`)

One way to find `folderId` is this:

```
var filename = "UU No 01 Th 2016 - Penjaminan";
var folderId = 2;

// note: <folderId> = 2021 - <year>
//       <year>     = 2021 - <folderId>
while (!filename.Contains($"{2021 - folderId}") && folderId < 76)
    folderId++;

// your SQL INSERT magic goes here
```

Comment: I have tried it, but there is a problem, namely: if year = 2015 (or other than 2016), then folder_id = 3 (it should change according to the year). For example year = 2015, folder_id = 4, etc.

Comment: I mean if you use the code even though year = 2015 then folder_id stays 3 and won't change.

Comment: @Rose, one more change

Comment: It works and I have one more problem, if I choose more than 1 item, then the sql statement that can be entered is only the first selected item. How to handle it?

Comment: @Rose, this is another question, but in short: you need to wrap your code in another loop and generate SQL INSERT at the end